# Hide overflow when the submenu is open

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a javascript to hide the overflow when the submenu is open. The exact same code is working in another HTML. Can anyone tell me what the error is and how I can correct this or achieve the same operation differently? I'm attaching part of my code for reference

```js
const USERINFO = document.getElementById("USERINFO");
const subMenu = document.getElementById("login-subMenu");
const html = document.documentElement;

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

USERINFO.addEventListener("click", function() {
  subMenu.style.right = "0";
  html.classList.add("dimmed");
  navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
});

html.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target !== USERINFO) {
    subMenu.style.right = "-500px";
    html.classList.remove("dimmed");
    document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'; // add this line
  } else {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; // add this line
  }
});

const closeButton = document.getElementById("closeButton");

closeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  subMenu.style.right = "-500px";
  html.classList.remove("dimmed");
  document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
});

subMenu.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#login-subMenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -500px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 9000;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="right_nav">
  <a id="USERINFO"> Help ></a>
</div>

<div id="login-subMenu">
  <button id="closeButton">Close X</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*I copied and pasted the js, but there were only 33 lines, not 37 as shown in the error?*

`var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");`

`navbar` is set to the element with id "navbar"
However, there is no element with an id of "navbar", so `navbar` becomes nothing, aka `null`, returning an error.
There is only `<div id="right_nav">` and `<div id="login-subMenu">`.
To fix this, create an element with id `navbar`, or change the ids.

Comment: Hey, I have an div with id as 'navbar'. It wraps 'right-nav' along with other divs. I used 'navbar' to create sticky and didnt think it was important for this code hence not mentioned it above. Even with inclusion of navbar, Im facing this problem.